# Using in operator in dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have to use "in" operator as I have to combine conditions in a dynamic query where I have something like this.

```
Declare  @sub varchar(200)  
Set @sub ='1,2' This value is coming from SSRS multivalue param selection 

Declare @commandtext nvarchar(max) 

set @commandtext = 'Select columnames from FROM view VW Where 1=1' 

if(@sub<>0 and @sub is not null and @sub <>'')  

set @commandText = @commandtext +  'and subid in (' + @sub  + ')'
```

But i have been receiving this and ofcourse it is due to datatype as subid is of type int in the view. But as I have checked other links, a delimiter function is suggested with join. But in my case I only have to apply in operator only. Is it any other way to convert the string to int and use it in "in" operator.

```
Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 49
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1,2' to data type int.
```

Comment: Something more is going on than what you're showing, because what you're showing shouldn't give you that conversion error.

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I agree; I kept looking for a place where an implicit conversion might be happening, but SQL Server should be treating all those pieces as text, not numbers.

Comment: Feels like we aren't being told the whole story here because the posted code should fail due to a syntax error on `... Where 1=1and ...`. Tell us more info and post the actual code that is failing?

Comment: What a catch experts! It was a blunder from my side. There was another condition where it was comparing the value with 0. I have just updated my question.

Comment: So, you've now located the source of the error - what further assistance are you looking for?

Comment: its all good. Thank you everybody.